# Responsive image lightbox

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, lightbox

I am trying to create a responsive photogalery. I've solved responsive thumbnails (they load the right image according to screen size and devicePixelRatio). But I also want a responsive lightbox for them. I hope there must be a suitable library...

The main problem is how to load only the correct image size. For example, on my 480*320 mobile phone, it is pointless to load 2Mpx images. However, on a 17" screen, it is basically what I want.

I hope this is simple, but I haven't found a suitable lightbox library. Well, lightboxing a HTML would be a solution, but it seems to be rarely supported. The Magnifier Popup supports it, but it seems to be aimed for some different purposes and I can't make it working for photogallery.

Comment: use bootstrap modal window https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/

Comment: Are you building your site with php? You can use adaptive-images.com and it will automatically load the correct size based on the device set up for your breakpoints. You can also use php-mobile-detect and serve up entirely different html.

Comment: BS modal is very low level. Adaptive-images (screen size based) are some approach shift for me, but I will think about it.